# Copy specific column header to new sheet if it meets certain criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to create a new row in Sheet 2 that consists of values from row 1 in Sheet 1.

Sheet 1 has:

```
   A    B     C     D       E      F
1 Bob  Sam   Ken  Allen   Henry   Ed
2 Yes  No    Yes  No      Yes     No
```

I want a formula to create row 1 in Sheet 2 with only those values where row 2 = "Yes".

So Sheet 2 would look like:

```
      A    B     C     D       E      F
 1    Bob  Ken  Henry
```

This would dynamically update as the data in Sheet one is updated.

Comment: what did you try till now?

Comment: Do you need a VBA answer or would a formula work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this formula will work (enter in A1 on Sheet 2, and drag right)

`=IF(Sheet1!A$2:$F$2="Yes",Sheet1!A$1:$F$1,"")`
Note: Enter as an array by pressing <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>.

Edit: I noticed that the formula above will leave a blank in between columns that have a "no" equivalent.  I'm trying to get a formula that removes the gap, but still allows a drag right.  The following does this *except* I can't figure out why "Bob", in A1, isn't being returned. It starts with "Sam". (Also enter as array)

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A1:$F1,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A2:$F2="Yes",COLUMN(Sheet1!$A1:$F1)-COLUMN(Sheet1!$A1)+1),COLUMNS(Sheet1!$A1:B1)))
```

Any ideas? I suspect it's something to do with my use of `Small()`. If you change it to `Large()`, the order that it returns is reversed

Here's the table:

[image]

and here's what Sheet2 looks like when using that array formula:

[image]
...What About Bob?!

(The #num is just because there's no more matches. Just throw an `IfError([array formula], "")` around the whole thing to remove this).

Edit2: **Got it!**  Use this formula, entered as an array formula:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A1:$F1,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A2:$F2="Yes",COLUMN(Sheet1!$A1:$F1)-COLUMN(Sheet1!$A1)+1),COLUMNS(Sheet1!$A1:A1))),"")`

(The final range should have been `$A1:A1`, not `$A1:B1`)

Comment: This formula almost gets me there, but it leave blank columns when there is a no...is there anyway to create the data in Sheet 2 without the blank columns?

Comment: @duger99 - My edit has a formula, but as I mentioned, it's not getting the left most name for some reason. :/    I'll keep trying to get that formula working.

Comment: Sorry BruceWayne, I must have been typing my comment when you posted...too bad I can't use them in reverse, it work just fine :) Thank you for continuing to try and figure this out...really appreciate it!!

Comment: @duger99 - figured it out! Check my final edit.  I also put the error checking around it, so it'll just leave blanks where there are no more matches.

Comment: I have no idea who you are talking about. .... and thanks, this was a first for me too (doing a formula that you can drag, that skips blanks), so writing it from almost scratch was a good exercise!

Comment: Impressive.  I would not even have known where to start with trying this as a formula. Wish I could up vote twice

Answer (score 0):

For VBA, because it was in the tags, put this in the worksheet events where the data is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("2:2")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim rng As Range

        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet5")'change to what ever sheet your want

        Dim strArr() As Variant
        ReDim strArr(0)
        With Target.Parent
            For Each rng In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight))
                If rng.Offset(1) = "Yes" Then
                    strArr(UBound(strArr)) = rng
                    ReDim Preserve strArr(UBound(strArr) + 1) As Variant

                End If
            Next rng
        End With
        If ubound(strArr) > 0 then
            ReDim Preserve strArr(UBound(strArr) - 1) As Variant
        End If
        ws.Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(strArr) + 1).Value = strArr
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Scott, I am getting a Subscript out of range error...My Yes/No answers are in a drop-down...Would that be causing an error with this line of code "ReDim Preserve strArr(UBound(strArr) - 1) As Variant"

Comment: @duger99 I forgot to deal with what happens when there are no "Yes".  See edit.

Comment: Also awesome! It is great to have options as this may get more complex as I go...thanks for staring me off on the right foot..